# Condition always true when reached in while loop

Tags: java, linked-list

I created a method to insert a Linked List node in the correct place of a sorted (increasing) linked list but I am having some problems.

```
public static void sortedInsert(LinkedListNode root, int value) {
        LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(value);
        if (root == null || root.data >= value) {
            newNode.next = root;
        } else {
            LinkedListNode curr = root;
            while (curr.next.data < value && curr.next != null) {
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            newNode.next = curr.next;
            curr.next = newNode;
        }
    }
```

errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinkedLists.LinkedListProblems.sortedInsert(LinkedListProblems.java:188)
```

The `curr.next != null` portion is highlighted in intellij so I'm assuming that is causing the error. This error only occurs when the value I added is bigger than the last value of the sorted linked list

However when the iterate to the last node of the linked list and the value of that node is still less than the value of the parameter. Shouldn't that exit the while loop?

Comment: Shouldn't your `while-loop` condition be reversed?  `while (curr.next != null && ...)` so that when it is `null` you're not trying to check it's data....which would cause a NPE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
while (curr.next.data < value && curr.next != null) {
  curr = curr.next;
}
```

You are testing in the wrong order, first check for `null` -

```
while (curr.next != null && curr.next.data < value) {
  curr = curr.next;
}
```

Otherwise when `curr.next` is `null` it will have already tested `curr.next.data < value` which will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your first if should be != null, and it should be an &&, otherwise you can have root.data being evaluated even when root is null.

```
if (root != null && root.data >= value) {
```

Comment: That should be && not ||

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an exception on that line because `cur.next.data` gets tested before `cur.next!=null`.

Swap them over and the `&&` will be short circuited correctly avoiding the exception.